# DataGridViewCheckBox not displaying correct value immediately. Is this a bug?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this code where I manually load up my DataGridView with values:

```
    void LoadRulesFromTemplate()
    {
        if (dgv.Columns.Count == 0) return;
        foreach (var r in _template.Rules.GetList())
        {
            var i = dgv.Rows.Add();
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Source"].Value = r.SourceFieldName;
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Destination"].Value = r.DestFieldName;
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Key"].Value = r.Key;
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Aggregate"].Value = r.Aggregate;
        }
    }
```

There is a button that loads an existing file, and in that process this is the last piece of code that gets run.  The DataGridView used to refresh perfectly at this point, but then I added a DataGridViewcheckBoxColumn.  It updates that column perfectly except for the very first row where the focus starts out at.  However, the moment you click on any other cell it suddenly fixes itself.

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but try setting the selection to null after loaded the data:

```
dgv.CurrentCell = null;
```

I don't know why this is happening, but if it's only with the first row, that usually gets selected, this might help.

Comment: Thanks!  That's definitely better than my first solution which was to move the selected row to another row and then back to the first one.